# How to move Tkinter widget precisely. Place method not working

Tags: python, tkinter, pycharm

Here's the code so far:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from Tkinter import *

#Creates game window
master = Tk()
master.geometry("640x480")
master.resizable(width = False, height = False)
master.title("YeeHaw Poker")

#Divides window into subsections
menuFrame = Frame(master, bg = "black", height = 60)
menuFrame.pack(fill = X, side = TOP)
tableFrame = Frame(master, highlightbackground = "black", highlightthickness = 4)
tableFrame.pack(fill = BOTH, expand = True)
optionsFrame = Frame(master, bg = "black", height = 100)
optionsFrame.pack(fill = X, side = BOTTOM)

#Draws poker table decorations
tableDecorations = Canvas(tableFrame, bg = "#771427", highlightthickness = 0)
tableDecorations.pack(fill = BOTH, expand = True)
#Renders window thus far so that dimensions can be found
master.update()
tWidth = tableDecorations.winfo_width()
tHeight = tableDecorations.winfo_height()
#Main edge
gap = 10
tableDecorations.create_rectangle(gap, gap, tWidth - gap, tHeight - gap, fill ="#277714", width = 4)
#Table outline
gap = 30
tableDecorations.create_rectangle(gap, gap, tWidth - gap, tHeight - gap, outline = "#35a31b", width = 2)
#Card outline coordinates
cardNum = 5
cardSize = 20
cardHeight = cardSize * 3.5
cardWidth = cardSize * 2.5
cardSpace = 10
cardTop = tHeight / 4
cardLeft = (tWidth - (cardNum * (cardWidth + cardSpace))) / 2
cardY1 = cardTop + cardHeight
cardY2 = cardTop
cardX1 = [0 for i in range(0, cardNum)]
cardX2 = [0 for i in range(0, cardNum)]
suit = [0 for i in range(0, cardNum)]

for i in range(0, cardNum):
    cardX1[i] = cardLeft + (i * (cardWidth + cardSpace))
    cardX2[i] = cardX1[i] + cardWidth
    suit[i] = Label(tableDecorations, text = "", bg = "white", font = (None, 50))
    suit[i].place(x = 5000, y  = 5000)

#Draws specified card in specified place
def drawCard(pos, type, pip):
    if type == "empty":
        tableDecorations.create_rectangle(cardX1[pos], cardY1, cardX2[pos], cardY2, outline = "#35a31b", width = 2)
        suit[pos].pack_forget()
    else:
        tableDecorations.create_rectangle(cardX1[pos], cardY1, cardX2[pos], cardY2, fill = "white", outline = "grey", width = 1)
        if type == "diamond":
            suit[pos].config(text = "♦", fg = "red")
        elif type == "heart":
            suit[pos].config(text = "♥", fg = "red")
        elif type == "spade":
            suit[pos].config(text = "♠", fg = "black")
        elif type == "club":
            suit[pos].config(text = "♣", fg = "black")
        suit[pos].pack()

#Creates new table
def newTable():
    for i in range(0, cardNum):
        drawCard(i, "diamond", 0)

newTable()

master.mainloop()
```

However this doesn't move the labels with the diamonds in at all, as shown here:

[image: Diamonds not moving]

It's infuriating...

I'm wanting the diamond to appear on each individual card, but clearly that's not happening here...

Any ideas?

Comment: Your title says "place method not working", but you aren't actually USING `.place()` in your code - you set an initial offscreen location for each suit that way, but then override it with `.pack()` in `drawCard()`.

Comment: Please create a [mcve]. You've included a lot of code that seems unrelated to the problem.

Comment: Why are you calling `place` in the first block of code, but then later calling `pack`?

Comment: Thanks I didn't realise place and pack contradict each other!

Comment: @numberjak is not that they contredict eachother. They are different geometry managers. `place()` is used for pixel location placement and `pack()` is used to arrange things relative to other widgets depending on their placement using `pack()`

Comment: You can only have one geometry manager manage a widget, so the last one that you call is the only one that has an effect.